# For categorical data, how to show results in a table, instead of lists? (Jupyter Notebook / Python)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm an entry level Python user who just started self-teaching use Python to do data analytics. These days I'm practicing with a Global Suicide Rate data in Jupyter Notebook on Kaggle. I met some problems with formatting my result.I'm wondering how to make my result in several lists, into a well-formatted table?

The dataset I's using is a Global Suicide Date data. For the following section of the code, I want to retrieve all country information in the min_year (which is 1985), and max_year (which is 2016).

So what I expected as my output is something like this: (just an example)

[image: Expected Output]

Following are my code.

```
country_1985 = data [(data['year']==min_year)].country.unique()
country_2016 = data [(data['year']==max_year)].country.unique()

print ([country_1985],[country_2016])
```

The result shows like this:

[image: Result]

However, I don't want those in a list. I'd like it to be shown in a **table format** something like this: 
[image: Result]

I tried to use pandas.DataFrame, also doesn't make any sense... Could anyone help me to solve my problem?

Updated:

Thanks for @Code Pope code!!! Thank you for your explanation and patience!

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


country_1985 = data [(data['year']==min_year)].country.unique()
country_2016 = data [(data['year']==max_year)].country.unique()

country_1985 = pd.DataFrame(country_1985.categories)
country_2016 = pd.DataFrame(country_2016.categories)

# Following are the code from @Code Pope

from IPython.display import display_html
def display_side_by_side(dataframe1, dataframe2):
modified_HTML=dataframe1.to_html() + dataframe2.to_html()
display_html(modified_HTML.replace('table','table 
style="display:inline"'),raw=True)

display_side_by_side(country_1985,country_2016 )
```

Then it looks like this:
[Updated Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9Zgh.png)

Comment: Are `country_1985` and `country_2016` dataframes?

Comment: @CodePope Thanks for your quick reply! I created those 2 new objects to help me find all country names in 1985, and all country names in 2016. Is that make sense?

Comment: your desired format in the picture is the format of the pandas dataframe. So if you want it, it is better to use pandas dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are saying that you are using Jupyter Notebook, you can change the html of your dataframes before displaying it. Use the following function:

```
from IPython.display import display_html
def display_side_by_side(dataframe1, dataframe2):
    modified_HTML=dataframe1.to_html() + dataframe2.to_html()
    display_html(modified_HTML.replace('table','table style="display:inline"'),raw=True)

# then call the function with your two dataframes
display_side_by_side(country_1985,country_2016 )
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for the code! After I ran it, it shows AttributeError: 'Categorical' object has no attribute 'to_html' . I'm sorry if I misunderstand anything because I'm just started to learn Python.

Comment: Ok. It seems that you are not using dataframes. You have to show your code. Somewhere you change your dataframe to categorical object. It would be best to avoid that and keep dataframes. Then you can use the above code

Comment: omg.... It works!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Yes, I have accepted this as the best answer. However when I tried to vote, it shows Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Comment: Ok. Interesting to know that :)